# How can I create a search code in Tweepy to automatically fetch data with specified date ranges

Tags: python, tweepy

How can I create a search code in Tweepy to automatically fetch data with specified date ranges e.g after fetching tweets in this time range (2020-10-01 to 2020-10-07) after that it automatically starts for another time range and (2020-10-07 to 2020-10-14)? Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 0):

You can query tweets using date ranges

```
    # start date
    date_since = datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
    # next day
    date_until = date_since + timedelta(days=1)

    # search (max 1000 tweets as example)
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='my query', since=date_since, until=date_until, count=100, lang="en").items(1000):
        print(tweet)
```

You can put the code above in a loop and pass the interval (instead adding a day you can add a week or something else). One consideration is to ensure you are not exhausting the Twitter rate limits (use `wait_on_rate_limit=True`, add sleep between iterations, etc..)